# parse external json source to html

Tags: javascript, json, html

I need to get some data from a json file stored at another server than my own. I've received the url of the file but have to "anonymize" it below, the url is exactly as below but with a different domain.

http://api.somedomain.com/v1/26963723e61eae69cefd/companies/5565592010/related-articles.json?languages=nor&per_page=10&page=2

Now I want to render the data in that file into a list or table structure in my html file, preferably after the page has loaded. If jQuery can be used for this then that would be great otherwise regular javascript will do.

Unless someone can toss up a solution I'd be happy to take pointers on where to turn to learn about how this can be done.

Comment: *I need to get some data from a json file stored at another server than my own.* — then the usual rules for getting content from other domains apply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)